# Model for fluctuating selection

Tags: evolution, mathematical-models, theoretical-biology, natural-selection

**Is there any mathematical model to predict the behaviour and long-term consequence of counter-acting selection at different time scale?**

For example, let's consider the bi-allelic gene **A**, with alleles **A<sub>1</sub>** and **A<sub>2</sub>**. During a long period of **n<sub>1</sub>** generations **A<sub>1</sub>** is slightly beneficial (differential of selection: **s<sub>1</sub>**). After this period, follows a short period of **n<sub>2</sub>** generations when **A<sub>2</sub>** is highly beneficial (differential of selection: **s<sub>2</sub>**).

What mathematical model describes the frequency fluctuations of alleles and which allele will get fixed at the long term given the initial frequency ( ***f<sub>0</sub>*** ), assuming infinite population size and random mating.

Comment: Unsmooth changes like you describe are normally hard to use in an analytical model. You could build a model of smoothly changing selection using a sine wave or simulations (which would be easy to build).

Comment: That remainds me the famous case of Biston betularia

Comment: Biston betularia is a moth that lives in England and has a light color in order to mimetize with the bark of trees. However, about 1% of the population presents melanism, and its camouflage fails. During the industrial revolution, the trees became dark as a result of the pollution. When that happened, the proportion of melanistic moths inverted, to almost 99%. During the 20st century, when the industry independized of the coal, the trees got light again, and the proportions restored once again.

Comment: This might be a gross oversimplification but could you not use sequential univariate breeders equations, model the response during the s1 phase, this will erode variation in favour of the A1 allele, then you could then apply the univariate equation to the s2 phase. If all variation was lost in the s1 phase then the response in the s2 phase will be 0, and increase dependent on the strength of selection and size of remaining variation.

Comment: GriffinEvo's response sounds right. But does the fluctuation continue indefinitely? In that case you might use the idea of step functions from EE to model the process.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I welcome you to develop a bit the idea and make an answer out of your comments. I have never heard of the step functions from EE (what does EE stands for?).

Comment: I'm going to look at some of your questions over the evenings this week and hope I will be able to answer them - no idea what is meant by EE @daniel

Comment: @GriffinEvo: electrical engineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frequency fluctuations will be determined by a standard model of selection as found in any basic population genetics text. In this scenario they take a very basic form: during each long period $i$ the frequency of $A_1$ increases from $f_i$ to $f_i\cdot (1+s_1)^{n_1}$ and during each short period $j$ the frequency of $A_1$ decreases from $f_j$ to $f_j\cdot (1/(1+s_2))^{n_2}.$ Thus over each pair of periods the frequency of $A_1$ changes by $(1+s_1)^{n_1}/(1+s_2)^{n_2}$. If this quantity exceeds 1, $A_1$ goes to fixation; if it is less than one $A_2$ goes to fixation.

More generally, for an infinite population in a fluctuating environment, the allele with the higher geometric mean fitness will go to fixation. Early discussions of these results are due to Dempster (1955; *Cold Spring Harbor Symp. Quant. Biol.*), Haldane and Jayakar (1963; *J. Genetics*), and Lewontin and Cohen (1969; *PNAS*).

Comment: Nice answer to a very old question! Thank you. I edited your answer just to clarify that $f_i$ and $f_j$ multiply the thing in parenthesis and are not function of the thing in parenthesis. just in case someone could have a doubt...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this model is a good approximation when the two phases are short enough. If the phases were to be too long then fixation may occur during the first phase and allele frequencies would never be affected by the second phase. This is even more important when $N$ and/or $s$ are high. It might be interesting to have such model for finite population.

Comment: Glad this was helpful. In the specific way that you formulated the question, we don't need to worry about fixation because the population is infinite and thus fixation can never occur. But as you note in the real world, or in a finite population model, fixation becomes a major issue. Off the top of my head I don't see how to derive a simple expression for the fixation probabilities of each allele in this case.