# What is the probability of fixation for a mutant under fluctuating selection?

Tags: evolution, population-genetics, theoretical-biology, natural-selection, population-dynamics

[Here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9920/model-for-fluctuating-selection/27808#27808) is an answer which explains how one can model the frequency of an allele that is under fluctuating selection (the selection that varies through time).

Not, thinking about fluctuating selection, there exist several derivations of the probability of fixation of an allele present at frequency $p$ with selection coefficient $s$ in a finite population of size $N$. For example, Kimura (using diffusion equations) approximated the probability of fixation $P_{fix}$ to be

$$P_{fix}≈\frac{1-e^{-4Ns} }{1-e^{-4Nsp}}$$

**How to model the probability of fixation (in a finite population) of an allele that undergoes fluctuating selection?**

I welcome one to answer by using whatever type of fluctuating selection. It might be an alternate of $s_1$ (uneven generation) and $s_2$ (even generation) or $s(t)$ might be a sinusoidal function of the time $t$ (in generations). Or $s$ might be drawn randomly from some distribution.